# Installing homebrew not possible under OS X 10.8.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, homebrew

I have installed the Xcode-Version 4.6.2 under OS X 10.8.3 and also the Command Line Tools. If I want to install homebrew with:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSkL raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/go)"
```

I get the error:

```
/Users/MarcoMueller/.rbenv/shims/ruby: line 21: /usr/local/Cellar/rbenv/0.4.0/libexec/rbenv: No such file or directory
```

What could be the problem?

Thank you

Comment: For more info try to run the command 'brew doctor'. What does it say?

Comment: Remove the rbenv shims from your ~/.bash_profile, I guess. It still points to an older installation of rbenv, you did install via homebrew before.

Comment: @SamuelJohn How do you remove the "rbenv shims"? i'm having this same problem

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem. It was solved by removing line eval `"$(rbenv init -)"` in my `~/.bash_profile`

Comment: i added  `eval "$(rbenv init -)"`  to my `~/.bash_profile` and fixed my issue